# How to populate array of arrays in react state variable?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

I'm trying to add an array to an array of arrays every function run. How can I append the array to my array of arrays state variable?

Here is my code:

```
const [volChart, setVolChart] = useState([])

function makeQueryHistorical(contract) {
   setVolChart([...volChart, days])
}

list.forEach((token) => {
   makeQueryhistorical(token.address)
})
```

Right now it only replaces the current value instead of adding a new array

Comment: How about `setVolChart([...volChart, ...days])`

Comment: can you able to add the structure of `contact` ?